# Button_click is not assigning TextBox values to object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonclick

I created a test object for the `UserInfo` class named `testUser`. When I use this, everything works fine and the object is found in the object list. When I assign textbox.text values to the object properties and click the submit button, the object is not created and does not show in the list at all(either that or the textbox values are not assigned to the properties..whichever). I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening. I tried messing around with `ViewState` and session variables but I'm at a total loss. It doesn't appear to be a state issue. Here is my code:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class CreateAccount : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<UserInfo> allUsersList = Application["AllUsersList"] as List<UserInfo>;
            UserInfo testUser = new UserInfo();
            testUser.FirstName = "Bob";
            testUser.MiddleInitials = "B";
            testUser.LastName = "Bob";
            testUser.EmailAddress1 = "Bob@gmail.com";
            testUser.EmailAddress2 = null;
            testUser.StreetAddress = "123 Bob Lane";
            testUser.AptNo = null;
            testUser.City = "BobTown";
            testUser.State = "TX";
            testUser.Zip = "77550";
            testUser.HomePhone = "5555555555";
            testUser.JobExperience = "None";
            testUser.Password = "bob1000";
            allUsersList.Add(testUser);


        }

        protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<UserInfo> allUsersList = Application["AllUsersList"] as List<UserInfo>;
            UserInfo newUser = new UserInfo();
            newUser.FirstName = firstName.Text;
            newUser.MiddleInitials = middleInitials.Text;
            newUser.LastName = lastName.Text;
            newUser.EmailAddress1 = emailAddress1.Text;
            newUser.EmailAddress2 = emailAddress2.Text;
            newUser.StreetAddress = streetAddress.Text;
            newUser.AptNo = aptno.Text;
            newUser.City = city.Text;
            newUser.State = state.Text;
            newUser.Zip = zip.Text;
            newUser.HomePhone = phone.Text;
            newUser.JobExperience = jobExperience.Text;
            newUser.Password = password.Text;
        }

        protected void CheckAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<UserInfo> allUsersList = Application["AllUsersList"] as List<UserInfo>;
            UserInfo testUser = new UserInfo();
            foreach (UserInfo item in allUsersList)
            {
                if (item.FirstName == "Bob")
                {
                    emailTextBox.Text = "Bob was found.";
                    //Note that this works and and it finds the testUser 
                    //value
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class design for the object:

```
namespace WebApplication1.App_Code
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        String firstName;
        String middleInitials;
        String lastName;
        String emailAddress1; 
        String emailAddress2;
        String streetAddress;
        String aptNo;
        String city;
        String state;
        String zip;
        String homePhone;
        String jobExperience;
        String password;
        public String FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; } 
            set { firstName = value; } 
        }
        public String MiddleInitials
        {
            get { return middleInitials; }
            set { middleInitials = value; }
        }
        public String LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }
        public string EmailAddress1
        {
            get { return emailAddress1; }
            set { emailAddress1 = value; }
        }
        public string EmailAddress2
        {
            get { return emailAddress2; }
            set { emailAddress2 = value; }
        }
        public string StreetAddress
        {
            get { return streetAddress; }
            set { streetAddress = value; }
        }
        public string AptNo
        {
            get { return aptNo; }
            set { aptNo = value; }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
            set { city = value; }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get { return state; }
            set { state = value; }
        }
        public string Zip
        {
            get { return zip; }
            set { zip = value; }
        }
        public string HomePhone
        {
            get { return homePhone; }
            set { homePhone = value; }
        }
        public string JobExperience
        {
            get { return jobExperience; }
            set { jobExperience = value; }           
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to asp.net and this is making me feel stupid. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update: This object is not being created and assigned to the list:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<UserInfo> allUsersList = Application["AllUsersList"] as List<UserInfo>;
    UserInfo newUser = new UserInfo();
    newUser.FirstName += firstName.Text;
    newUser.MiddleInitials = middleInitials.Text;
    newUser.LastName = lastName.Text;
    newUser.EmailAddress1 = emailAddress1.Text;
    newUser.EmailAddress2 = emailAddress2.Text;
    newUser.StreetAddress = streetAddress.Text;
    newUser.AptNo = aptno.Text;
    newUser.City = city.Text;
    newUser.State = state.Text;
    newUser.Zip = zip.Text;
    newUser.HomePhone = phone.Text;
    newUser.JobExperience = jobExperience.Text;
    newUser.Password = password.Text;
    allUsersList.Add(newUser);
    Application["AllUsersList"] = allUsersList;
}
```

Why are the textbox values not being assigned to the object properties? Why is this object not being created and added to the list? I've run tests and the main list is always empty and nothing placed in it.

Comment: Check what is the use for the property [Page.IsPostBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_Page_IsPostBack) and better read [Asp.Net Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add the filled list to `Application["AllUsersList"]` after adding items to your list. So you need something like this in your code:

```
allUsersList.Add(testUser);
Application["AllUsersList"] = allUsersList;
```

Also in every [postback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_Page_IsPostBack), you are always getting the old values, so you need to use the following condition in your `Page-Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<UserInfo> allUsersList = Application["AllUsersList"] as List<UserInfo>;
        ....
        ....
        allUsersList.Add(testUser);
        Application["AllUsersList"] = allUsersList;
    }
}
```

Comment: @EricBooker Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work